# constructing a date column from a relative time pd.df column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-3.6

I am looking to add a column 'expiry' to the following df:

```
In [157]: df
Out[157]: 
     atmVol     t
0  0.043220  0.02
1  0.042139  0.04
2  0.041174  0.06
3  0.040328  0.08
4  0.039606  0.10
5  0.038364  0.15
6  0.037971  0.20
7  0.038480  0.25
```

tried this:

```
df['expiry'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(x.t * 365)
```

which returns a AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 't'", 'occurred at index atmVol')

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with one column:

```
df['expiry'] = df['t'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(x * 365))
```

Or convert column `t` to `timedelta`s by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['expiry'] = datetime.utcnow() + pd.to_timedelta(df['t'] * 365, unit='d')
```

---

```
df['expiry1'] = df['t'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(x * 365))
df['expiry2'] = datetime.utcnow() + pd.to_timedelta(df['t'] * 365, unit='d')
print (df)
     atmVol     t                    expiry1                    expiry2
0  0.043220  0.02 2018-02-01 21:14:02.057250 2018-02-01 21:14:02.057250
1  0.042139  0.04 2018-02-09 04:26:02.057250 2018-02-09 04:26:02.057250
2  0.041174  0.06 2018-02-16 11:38:02.057250 2018-02-16 11:38:02.057250
3  0.040328  0.08 2018-02-23 18:50:02.057250 2018-02-23 18:50:02.057250
4  0.039606  0.10 2018-03-03 02:02:02.057250 2018-03-03 02:02:02.057250
5  0.038364  0.15 2018-03-21 08:02:02.057250 2018-03-21 08:02:02.057250
6  0.037971  0.20 2018-04-08 14:02:02.057250 2018-04-08 14:02:02.057250
7  0.038480  0.25 2018-04-26 20:02:02.057250 2018-04-26 20:02:02.057250
```

Comment: both work super. surprisingly the apply version is faster. Thanks jezrael

Comment: Yes, I test it too. I think because `to_timedelta` working with `NaT` also, so slowier.

Comment: I get this timings `In [308]: %timeit datetime.utcnow() + pd.to_timedelta(df['t'] * 365, unit='d')
1 loop, best of 3: 284 ms per loop

In [309]: %timeit df['t'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(x * 365))
10 loops, best of 3: 153 ms per loop`

Comment: with `80000 rows` by `df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: small df so doesnt matter much. you answer is great as always